# Is it possible to run alphanet and zeronet nodes from the same server that is running a mainnet node?

Tags: node, alphanet, zeronet

When running a non-baking mainnet node on a Mac, is it possible to start an alphanet and/or zeronet node alongside the mainnet?

Can I just build them each in their own directory? And then what about the network ports?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As for how to run the three separate nodes, to build off of adrian's answer you could use the following options when running the node:

```
/home/tezos/tezos_mainnet/tezos-node run --data-dir /home/tezos/.tezos-node --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1:8732
/home/tezos/tezos_alphanet/tezos-node run --data-dir /home/tezos/.tezos-node-alpha --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1:8733
/home/tezos/tezos_zeronet/tezos-node run --data-dir /home/tezos/.tezos-node-zero --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1:8734
```

You'll have to generate an identity for each node:

```
/home/tezos/tezos_mainnet/tezos-node identity --data-dir /home/tezos/.tezos-node generate 26.
/home/tezos/tezos_alphanet/tezos-node identity --data-dir /home/tezos/.tezos-node-alpha generate 26.
/home/tezos/tezos_zeronet/tezos-node identity --data-dir /home/tezos/.tezos-node-zero generate 26.
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible to run all three at the same time on the same machine.

You have to ensure that they each have a different directory. Furthermore you need to configure the ports in the config files so that they don't clash.

Comment: I think the actual question was rather ‘how’ not ‘if’ 

Comment: So alpha and zeronet cannot be run from the mainnet directory, i.e. using the data from the mainnet? That would save a lot of data and bootstrapping time and space